# Redirect non register user from post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I really need your help. I need to configure a redirection of non registered users from a specific wp custom post type. For this purpose I use this code in my function.php:

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_post_type_single');
    function redirect_post_type_single(){

```
    if ( ! is_singular( 'sfwd-lessons' ) && ! is_user_logged_in())
    return;
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.google.com/', 301 ); exit;
}
```

But this code does not work as it should. Redirection occurs but redirects all in a row. I don’t understand why? Please save my time who is understand in this matter.

Comment: Well probably because the condition you formulated there is _not_ true …? (Why are you going with a “negated” condition here in the first place?)

Comment: I use 'negation' because if I use is_singular( 'sfwd-lessons' ) and so it seems logical, a redirect does not occur at all. For me this is a strange thing, I can’t understand what I’m missing.

Comment: If you want to redirect everyone trying to access you CPT, you should remove the first negation and put `wp_redirect` into the conditional block.

Comment: Maybe you are not testing the _right_ thing with `is_singular` to begin with …? Check https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/, it has more explanations on what is considered what in WP.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_singular( 'sfwd-lessons' ) && ! is_user_logged_in()) {   
  wp_redirect( 'https://www.google.com/', 301 );
  die; 
}
```

If is 'sfwd-lessons' and the user is not logged in, redirect to "your url" and prevent the execution of remaining code

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. I understand that this should work. But does not work ( Not even a redirect. Take a look at the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/r09ifr (this is login user) and here is non loging: https://prnt.sc/r09j9z Only Google favicon appears, and in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help this code is really work great for my purpose. There was some erro in the function.php file. All issue was caused only one extra brace.